# Execute 'SET a = b' query

Tags: php, database, activerecord, codeigniter

I want to execute 'SET a = b' query using Active Record in Codeigniter. I am using MySQL.
I tried with

```
$this->db->set('a', 'b', FALSE);
```

But it executes

```
SET a = NULL
```

Comment: Are you trying to update or insert a row? Maybe show all of the code belonging to this statement, so we can investigate what's going on exactly.

Comment: Indeed; let's see the code, and perhaps you could tell us whether 'a' and 'b' are column names, and if those columns are in the same table, etc. -- some clue as to what operation you actually want to perform here, and on what database objects, would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

`$this->db->query('SET a = b')`

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

- Christian

Comment: That's not a query, of course. And it doesn't provide the abstraction level, which Active Record does.

Comment: It's a query but it does not return anything. You can use the query() method to perform 'write' type queries. If the ORM doesn't have a way to perform SET queries, this is a viable solution. Besides SET query doesn't return anything. Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-option.html